# Is there a way around this c# type inference failure?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, type-inference

I have the following C# extension method of IObserver. It enables me to put LINQ expressions at the head of it by using an intermediate subject.

```
/// <summary>
/// Given an IObserver we may wish to build a new IObserver that has LINQ
/// combinators at it's head.
///
///     observer = observer.Wrap(observable=>observable.Where(k=>k>0));
///
/// </summary>
public static IObserver<U>
 Wrap<T,U>
 ( this IObserver<T> This
 , Func<IObservable<U>, IObservable<T>> fn 
 )
{
    var s = new Subject<U>();
    fn(s).Subscribe(This);
    return s;
}
```

However when I use the method

```
    [Fact]
    public void WrapShouldWrapObservers()
    {
        var b = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2,3,4,5 };
        var s = new Subject<int>();
        var c = new List<int>();

        var obs = s.Wrap(observable => observable.Where(k => k > 3));

        s.Subscribe(v => c.Add(v));

        b.ToObservable().Subscribe(obs);
        c.Should().BeEquivalentTo(4, 5);

    }
```

I get the error that

```
Error   2   The type arguments for method

ReactiveUI.Ext.IObservableMixins.Wrap<T,U>
( System.IObserver<T>
, System.Func<System.IObservable<U>,System.IObservable<T>>
)

cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
explicitly.
```

When I put in the type args explicitly then it works.

```
    var obs = s.Wrap<int,int>(observable => observable.Where(k => k > 3));
```

However from inspection there is no ambiguity if I leave the type args out. What is the problem here?

**-----------ANSWER------------**

If I change the test case to exercise the types properly then it becomes obvious what the problem is

```
    [Fact]
    public void WrapShouldWrapObservers()
    {
        var b = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2,3,4,5 };
        var s = new Subject<string>();
        var c = new List<string>();

        var obs2 = s.Wrap<int,string>(observable => observable.Where(k => k > 3).Select(k=>k.ToString()));

        s.Subscribe(v => c.Add(v));

        b.ToObservable().Subscribe(obs2);
        c.Should().BeEquivalentTo("4", "5");
    }
```

It is not possible to know what `observable` the first argument to the lambda should be. The lambda must return IObservable but there are an infinite number of type observable could be to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the observer in your lambda could be any type. If you're just going to use LINQ operators that can't transform types, you could do this:

```
public static IObserver<T> Wrap<T> (this IObserver<T> this, 
    Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<T>> fn)
{
    var s = new Subject<T>();
    fn(s).Subscribe(this);
    return s;
}
```

Else, you will have to do it differently, specifying the `IObserver` type:

```
var obs = s.Wrap((IObserver<int> observer) => observer.Where(k => k > 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no way, using an lambda expression to infer the type `U` from the parameters.

You can get around the by specifying the expression type elsewhere, like this:

```
Func<IObservable<int>, IObservable<int>> wrapper = o => o.Where(k => k > 3);
var obs = s.Wrap(wrapper);
```

Or this

```
private IObservable<int> Wrapper(IObservable<int>> o)
{
    return o.Where(k => k > 3);
}

var obs = s.Wrap(this.Wrapper);
```

You might also be able to get around it by creating a different overload that *could* be inferred from the parameters:

```
public static IObserver<T> Wrap<T>
    ( this IObserver<T> This
    , Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<T>> fn )
{
    return This.Wrap<T, T>(fn);
}

var obs = s.Wrap(observer => observer.Where(k => k > 3));
```

Of course in this case, this will only work when the parameter type and return type are the same.